# I am using TeXmaker editor and MiKTeX distribution on windows 10 - update failed

Tags: texmaker, miktex-update

Before MiKTeX actualization I used PdfLaTeX as a compiler.

After the MiKTeX actualization, I've tried compiling the same code and the error

```
:the order is not executable. pdflatex - synctex=1 - imteraction=nonstopmode %.tex .
```

The follow error:

```
Sorry, but pdflatex did not succeed`. The log hopefully contains the
information to get MiKTeX going again: `C\users.....\pdflatex.log.
```

This error happened after that I did an actualization on MiKTeX. Before, all compilations process works fully.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you try compiling from the command line?

Comment: Do you really have a space between the - and the option? Also, you have imteraction rather than interaction (m instead of n) in the second option.

Comment: I maked an error on the question. The correc parameters used werepdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex